# asp.net MVC2 - can not config folder View in folder Worldstore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

example like:

```
Content
Controller
Model
Worldstore
---- Views
---- ----- Home
---- ----- ---- Index.aspx
```

......

How can i config to let my website run through the dir: ~/Worldstore/Views/...

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Why are you using MVC2? It's really, really old.

Comment: i know it was old, but that project cannot run on the MVC3 or 4 ...
Can you help me to solve my problems?
Thanks

Comment: did you think about Area ?

Comment: i have thought about Area, but Area structure is not in my intention for this project. I want to config to run as my question about "run through the dir: ~/worldstore/Views/.."